# Get content of first 5 rows and echo them

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I have written query for this. Query is correct but dont know why it does not echo anything:

```
$sql3= mysqli_query($con,"select post from facebook_posts where p_id >  (select MAX(p_id) - 5 from facebook_posts);");
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($sql3))
{
    echo $row['post'];
    echo '<br/>';

}
```

Table has data already. When I test query in mysql it gives 5 row content;

Comment: Consider using *ORDER BY* and *LIMIT* to avoid nested select queries.
SELECT post FROM facebook_posts ORDER BY p_id DESC LIMIT 0,5

Comment: @Capricorn watch the details facebook_posts sounds like an large table.. the sub query that Karimkhan is using will scale better on large tables..   see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06807/1  ... looks like sorting takes the longest time.. but optimizing the subquery takes longer so your query would be better on smaller datasets vs the subquery.. also the subquery triggers an range scan what is better vs an an FULL table scan what the ORDER BY.. DESC would trigger and filesort is tricky with an large number off records.

Comment: @Karimkhan +1 for using an subquery see mine last comment to Capricorn for an explainment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions. The `mysql_fetch_array` function cannot fetch any results when you executed the query with `mysqli_query`. You shouldn't be using the `mysql_*` functions anymore since they are deprecated.

Also, if you want to limit your results in MySQL, you can use the `LIMIT`-clause instead of calculating a maximum/minimum id.

If you change your code into the following, it should work.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select post from facebook_posts where p_id >  (select MAX(p_id) - 5 from facebook_posts)");
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  echo $row['post'];
  echo '<br/>';
}
```

For more information about fetching results using mysqli, you can look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Answer (score 2):

First you use `mysqli` library for query and then you try to use `mysql` to fetch a row.

`mysql` and `mysqli` are different libraries. You should use only one of them. Since `mysql` is deprecated, you should use `mysqli` from these two.